# Using bootstrap to compare two ensemble correlations

Tags: correlation, bootstrap

I am asking for your help because I'm not sure whether the procedure I'm using is correct.

I have two models, M1 and M2, and for each of them I have ten instances (ensemble members). For each model I calculate the output mean of all the members inside the ensemble. Then I compute the correlation between this ensemble mean and the observations (28 time samples).
I'd like to know if the difference between the two correlations, i.e. the two models, is "significant", i.e. it's due to the difference between the two models' parameters and structure.

I am using a bootstrap procedure. For each iteration:

1. I create two new ensembles resampling with replacement from the 10+10 initial instances
2. I calculate the new ensemble means and the correlations with the observations
3. I calculate the difference between the two correlations

At the end, I have a vector of correlation differences that I use to get the 5-95% percentiles. Then I check whether the original difference (the real one) is inside or outside the percentiles' range.

That's the whole story.